# InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: user data directory is already in use error using --user-data-dir to start Chrome using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, invalidargumentexception

When I am trying to use `--user-data-dir` for the current user to start Chrome using Selenium I am getting an error as:

```
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: user data directory is already in use, please specify a unique value for --user-data-dir argument, or don't use --user-data-dir
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Could You describe your example more clearly ??? Provide what you tried, what is used version? Why not try example from chromedriver page and check if it works ??

Comment: Please check here on how to ask questions on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please add the code you are using to open the browser and go to the page.

Comment: import logging
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

def test_3_2():
    logging.debug("running test_3_2")
    driver.get("https://docs.python.org/")
    logging.info("URL: " + driver.current_url)
    logging.info("Title: " + driver.title)
    assert "Documentation" in driver.title 
    driver.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  test_3_2()

Comment: I have added the code I am running above

Comment: This error is showing up because you are running Chrome with that user while you have a Chrome Window open already with that user. It will probably work when you close Chrome or use a different user.

Answer (score 21):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: user data directory is already in use, please specify a unique value for --user-data-dir argument, or don't use --user-data-dir
```

...implies that the *ChromeDriver* was unable to initiate the new *Chrome Browser* session using the specified `user data directory` as it was already in use.

This error can be reproduced as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  import getpass

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument(r"--user-data-dir=C:\Users\{}\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data".format(getpass.getuser()))
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
  ```
- Complete relevant traceback:

  ```
  [12148:21412:0204/035557.731:ERROR:cache_util_win.cc(21)] Unable to move the cache: Access is denied. (0x5)
  [12148:21412:0204/035557.731:ERROR:cache_util.cc(141)] Unable to move cache folder C:\Users\Soma Bhattacharjee\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\ShaderCache\GPUCache to C:\Users\Soma Bhattacharjee\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\ShaderCache\old_GPUCache_000
  [12148:21412:0204/035557.731:ERROR:disk_cache.cc(178)] Unable to create cache
  [12148:21412:0204/035557.731:ERROR:shader_disk_cache.cc(605)] Shader Cache Creation failed: -2
  Opening in existing browser session.
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Soma Bhattacharjee\Desktop\Debanjan\PyPrograms\yandex_ru.py", line 18, in <module>
      driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
    File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 81, in __init__
      desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
    File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
      self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
    File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
      response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
    File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
      self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
      raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
  selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: user data directory is already in use, please specify a unique value for --user-data-dir argument, or don't use --user-data-dir
  ```

---

### Analysis

The error stack trace clearly complains of **Access is denied** as the program was unable to move the cache folder `..\ShaderCache\GPUCache` to `..\ShaderCache\old_GPUCache_000`. hence the creation of **cache** failed and subsequently creation of **Shader Cache Creation** failed. Though these issues raises the `InvalidArgumentException` but forcefully able to open a new window within the existing *Chrome Browser Session*.

Though the error is thrown, still the new Chrome window gets initiated but remains attached with the already opened *Chrome* session but the new window can't be controlled by the [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) instance. Hence you see `data:,` in the url bar.

---

### Solution

You need to take care of a couple of things:

- If you are using the *Default Chrome Profile* to access webpages for your other work on the same *Test Machine*, you shouldn't set **`user-data-dir`** as the **User Data** as it remains locked by the other Chrome process you have initiated manually.

  - In the above scenario you need to create and use another *Chrome Profile* and you can find a detailed discussion in [How to open a Chrome Profile through Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49270109/how-to-open-a-chrome-profile-through-python/49280195#49280195)
- If you are executing your tests in a isolated *test system*, you can set **`user-data-dir`** as **..\User Data\Default** to access the *Default Chrome Profile*.

  - In the above scenario you need to create and use another *Chrome Profile* and you can find a detailed discussion in [How to use Chrome Profile in Selenium Webdriver Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52394408/how-to-use-chrome-profile-in-selenium-webdriver-python-3/52399027#52399027)
- However as per best practices you must always create a new *Chrome Profile* to execute your tests as the *Default Chrome Profile* may contain *Extensions*, *Bookmarks*, *Browsing History*, etc, and may not load properly.

  - You can find a detailed discussion in [How to open a Chrome Profile through --user-data-dir argument of Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50635087/how-to-open-a-chrome-profile-through-user-data-dir-argument-of-selenium/50637211#50637211)

Comment: But I need my existing session of the browser to stay. While I carry forward with a Selenium test with the same user profile. How could you do that?

Comment: @Jitin Let's discuss in details within [Selenium Chat Room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium)

Comment: @undetectedSelenium how do you get the full traceback to see which files are being accessed?

Answer (score 5):

The simplest and easiest fix is; to clear existing opened chrome driver: Here're the steps: type task manager to the Spotlight Search/in the Search Window at the task bar or using other ways accessing to task manager. When the Task Manager Wizard/window pops up, search chromedriver, right click on it and then click "End Task". That's it. It's not an eternal fix. Once you opened chrome browser multiple times, you got to do the same step avoid the issue. Hope this helps as am looking for a stable fix.

Answer (score 2):

Just had the same problem trying to skip the login process and the solution was to close the already openned browser.

Answer (score 1):

As [Tes answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61760641/7159520) mentioned, I opened up the Windows Task Manager and I closed all the chrome.exe and chromedriver.exe processes and it worked!!!

I used these configurations to open Google Chrome using my Chrome Profile:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\my_user\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='./chromedriver.exe', options=options)
```

Comment: do you know how this would work on a macbook? `/Users/user_name/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default` didn't work

Answer (score -4):

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://Users//Mhamed//Desktop//chromedriver.exe");

```
               ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

                                options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);

                      WebDriver        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

                



        

  driver.manage().window().fullscreen();

         driver.get("");
```

Comment: Please answer in a neat & tidy manner. make sure you use the code tag properly and add a simple explanation.