# Selenium error message (nvalidArgumentException)

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, invalid-argument

When I am trying to use Selenium I am getting an error as:

```
nvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: user data directory is already in use, please specify a unique value for --user-data-dir argument, or don't use --user-data-dir
```

my code :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver\chromedriver.exe')
# request url
driver.get('https://jamalon.com/ar/best-seller-books-2019')
#give it some time
sleep(2)
## retrive , download html page
html = driver.page_source
#close
driver.close()
```

i try to do same solution here but i get same error :(
[InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: user data directory is already in use error using --user-data-dir to start Chrome using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59987080/invalidargumentexception-message-invalid-argument-user-data-directory-is-alre)

Comment: try giving absolute path to your chromedriver.exe

Comment: i do .. nothing change

Comment: Possible duplicate. check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59987080/invalidargumentexception-message-invalid-argument-user-data-directory-is-alre

Answer (score 0):

First if you're using Pycharm then keep your chromedriver.exe in the location where your current python file is located.

Then use the below code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# request url
driver.get('https://jamalon.com/ar/best-seller-books-2019')
#give it some time
time.sleep(2)
## retrive , download html page
html = driver.page_source
print(html)
#close
driver.close()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Amar , i use Jupyter notebook ,, i try the cod but i get same error agian

Comment: Then include the chromedriver path inside the webdriver.Chrome("<chromedriver path>) function.

Comment: Just keep the format of the path like this :- 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\GSC-30431\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\chromedriver.exe')

Comment: Or keep the chromedriver file along with the jupyter notebook file, both in the same path. and don't include path under the paranthesis eg- driver = webdriver.Chrome(). That will also work.

Comment: i change it to: driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\LAM\Desktop\DSI\project3\project-3\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe')  ... 
The page opens but with the error ..

Comment: chromedriver file with the jupyter notebook in the same file ..... i check (Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\)  I didn't find selenium
is this wrong