# How to use specific Chrome profile with selenium python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, chrome-profile

Please don't mark this is as duplicate first read my problem properly..

This is my code:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(r"--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Pranil.DESKTOP-TLQKP4G.000\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
options.add_argument(r'--profile-directory=Profile 1')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
browser.get('https://web.whatsapp.com')
```

And this is the error I get:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: user data directory is already in use, please specify a unique value for --user-data-dir argument, or don't use --user-data-dir
```

I tried the solutions given here:
[InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: user data directory is already in use error using --user-data-dir to start Chrome using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59987080/invalidargumentexception-message-invalid-argument-user-data-directory-is-alre)

The problem is that the Default and Profile 1 are in the same directory User Data(Creating a new profile doesn't solve the problem as mentioned in above answer)..So if I run this script with my  another chrome tab with 'Default' profile running in background this error appears..How can I make sure that this error goes away(I can't close the other chrome tabs with Default profile while running this script)

Comment: Please check the link https://stackoverflow.com/a/62909989/12870513

Comment: I have already visited that link and I mentioned it in my answer..I want to run instances of chrome with other profile running.I can't close them...Is there any other option?