# Stay logged in with Selenium using Chrome default profile

Tags: python, selenium, automation, automated-tests

I want to use selenium with my Google profile, I created this code:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 

options.add_argument(r"user-data-dir=C:\Users\myprofile\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data") #Path to my chrome profile

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\chromedriver.exe", options=options)

driver.get(url)
```

I got this error:

```
InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: user data directory is already in use, please specify a unique value for --user-data-dir argument, or don't use --user-data-dir
```

I also tried another profile, but return the same error:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 

options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=C:/Users/mxs/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data')
options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Profile 2')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\chromedriver.exe", options=options)

driver.get(url)
```

also, I tried codes in both Jupyter Notebook and VSCode

Comment: I usually copy `User Data` of my Chrome where I'm logged in to sites in a seperate folder and pass that in as parameter to the ChromeDriver.

Comment: this happens when another instance of Chrome is open using the same data.  Not sure if google will let a bot login though...

Comment: does these links work for your case? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59987080/invalidargumentexception-message-invalid-argument-user-data-directory-is-alre) (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50635087/how-to-open-a-chrome-profile-through-user-data-dir-argument-of-selenium/50637211#50637211) the second link is used for c# but the logic is similar.

Answer (score 0):

#### Suggestion 1

If you are okay with only one selenium process running at a time, you can use queue to achieve it. As long as you use only one process to access user-dir, it'll not cause any error.

#### Suggestion 2

If you are trying to stay logged in for some website, you can reuse cookies. In this case you don't need to use `user-data-dir` thing. Selenium will automatically create temporary `user-data-dir` on every run.

#### Suggestion 3

If you still want to use the same profile for every session, here is the hack to do it. You keep original --user-data-dir unused, instead you copy all the content of your original profile directory to some temporary directory and use it with --user-data-dir every time you initiate chrome selenium.

Comment: suggestion 2 seems fine, how to do it ?

Comment: Please check out steps I've written here - https://dev.to/hardiksondagar/reuse-sessions-using-cookies-in-python-selenium-12ca

Comment: how to stores cookies on pickle file ? I get cookies using the chrome extension 'EditThisCookie' and I whant to login to this webpage https://betsapi.com/rs/pinnaclesports/2852774/BOOM-ID-v-Neon-Esports

Comment: It would be nice if you could add some code snippet on how to achieve those suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

## **Suggestion**

When you are trying to run your python script close all the chrome windows. I got the error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: user data directory is already in use, please specify a unique value for --user-data-dir argument, or don't use --user-data-dir
```

when I had one of the chrome windows open. So it is better to close all the chrome windows and try again.