# Error in Python Selenium just for loading a page

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Here's my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument(r'--user-data-dir=C:\Users\Winsome\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data')
options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Profile 4')
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
options.add_argument('log-level=3')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver', options=options)
driver.get("https://github.com")
```

When I run the code, I get an error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "app.py", line 10, in
>
> driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver', options=options)   File
> "C:\Users\Winsome\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py",
> line 81, in **init**
> desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)   File "C:\Users\Winsome\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
> line 157, in **init**
> self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)   File "C:\Users\Winsome\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
> line 252, in start_session
> response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)   File "C:\Users\Winsome\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
> line 321, in execute
> self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "C:\Users\Winsome\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py",
> line 242, in check_response
> raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid
> argument: user data directory is already in use, please specify a
> unique value for --user-data-dir argument, or don't use
> --user-data-dir

I am sure that I have no chrome windows open, but I don't know why I'm getting the error :(
Can anyone help?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Obviously, Windows.

Comment: Well can you check your argument which you are passing in the .add_argument() I can see it displays `InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument`

Comment: @YaDavMaNish Can you give me the code for that?

Comment: @AbhirajshriWinsome check the ref link in the answer

Answer (score 0):

Closing all Chrome tabs does not mean that Chrome is not running in the background.

For Windows, please open Task Manager (Ctrl + Alt + Delete) and look in the Processes tab for any Chrome related processes.

Comment: I even restarted my PC, but same error again :(

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line

```
options.add_argument(r'--user-data-dir=C:\Users\Winsome\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data')
```

from your code.
Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60048564/3485434) for more deep and clear explanations

Comment: But it is loading the page in some anonymous profile... but I wanted in profile 4 only

Comment: I see. have you tried to set user-data-dir as ..\User Data\Default to access the Default Chrome Profile as described there?

Comment: Yes, I did. But still it's opening in some anyonymous profile

Comment: Well, I currently have no much time, sorry. Upvoted and leaved for now :)

Comment: :'( 
ok, I'll be waiting until you reply

Comment: I hope someone else will be able to help here

Answer (score 0):

Reference PC Build info: Windows 11 (22622.290), Google Chrome (103.0.5060.114), selenium (4.3.0), ChromeDriver (103.0.5060.53)

I confirmed that this worked for me:

```
from selenium import webdriver

# add chrome options
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\dtada\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
chrome_options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Profile 1')
# point to path of chromedriver
s = Service('C:/bin/chromedriver.exe')
# initialize the Chrome driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, service_args=["--verbose", "--log-path=C:\\bin\\qc1.log"], options=chrome_options)

# go to webpage
driver.get(url)
```