# Admin forced profile login within Selenium using Edge in Python

Tags: python, selenium, admin, microsoft-edge, selenium-edgedriver

I'm designing a tool using Selenium with Edge in python. I've got the following code.

```
from msedge.selenium_tools import Edge, EdgeOptions

edge_options = EdgeOptions()
edge_options.use_chromium = True
edge_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\XXX\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Edge\\User Data"); 
edge_options.add_argument("profile-directory=Default");

edge_options.binary_location = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"
browser = Edge(EdgeChromiumDriverManager(log_level=30).install(), options=edge_options)
browser.get(url)
```

I'm succesfully creating a browser, however when there's already a browser opened I get the following error, which can be solved [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59987080/invalidargumentexception-message-invalid-argument-user-data-directory-is-alre) Ultimately it is kind of bad practice using Default profile, since the user interferes with the edgedriver.

`user data directory is already in use, please specify a unique value for --user-data-dir argument, or don't use --user-data-dir`

There's multiple fixes, however creating a new profile is easiest by changing profiles.

```
edge_options.add_argument("profile-directory=Profile x");
```

This is where my trouble begins, the following options are given within the automated browser: [Your admin needs you to sign in. To use profile x, please sign in or switch to a different account.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J004B.png)

Basically I'm forced to create a second instance of the same account, switching me back to the initial default profile. Which only works if the user is not using Edge while the tool is running, something I cannot guarantee. Is there a workaround given I don't have admin rights?

Comment: According to your description, I found that this problem should be caused by setting the relevant group policy, simply refer to [Browser sign-in settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#browser-sign-in-settings). So you can't skip this group policy to achieve your needs. What you can do is log in as admin account, or modify this policy configuration mentioned aboved.

Comment: Hi, 
Have you found any solutions on this?