# Getting IllegalArgumentException when running jmeter webdriver script

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter

I recently started using the jmeter with selenium webdriver with a sample test and when I run the script the chrome browser is launched but not navigated to the site. I have installed the chromedriver and specified the path in the Chrome Driver Config. Please find the ss below.

[image]

[image]

In the jmeter.log file this is the error I see

> 2022-03-09 15:51:35,665 ERROR o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Error calling threadStarted org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: invalid
> argument: user data directory is already in use, please specify a
> unique value for --user-data-dir argument, or don't use
> --user-data-dir Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z'
> os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'x86',
> os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_321' Driver info:
> driver.version: ChromeDriver
>
> 2022-03-09 15:51:35,666 ERROR o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Error while
> processing sampler: 'jp@gc - WebDriver Sampler'.
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Browser has not been configured.
> Please ensure at least 1 WebDriverConfig is created for a ThreadGroup.
> at
> com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.sampler.WebDriverSampler.sample(WebDriverSampler.java:62)
> ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-3.3.jar:?]     at
> org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:638)
> ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.3]    at
> org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:558)
> ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.3]    at
> org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:489)
> [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.3]     at
> org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256)
> [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.3]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
> [?:1.8.0_321]

Not sure why its not identifying the chrome driver. I even tried to close all the open browsers and still having the same issue. In the first error it says do not use the user-data-dir. How do I configure that in jmeter.
One more thing that I am user client laptop with limited access. So I can't create or use new user profile in my chrome. The chrome is managed by my organization.
Thanks

Comment: See similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59987080/invalidargumentexception-message-invalid-argument-user-data-directory-is-alre

Comment: @user7294900, I have already looked in to that and the solution mentioned in that question is to create new user profile from the chrome settings. And as i already mentioned that my chrome settings are managed by my organization and I can't create new profile. Is there anyway to do from the code or add commands in the properties files?

Answer (score 0):

The error means that Chrome's [User Data Directory](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/user_data_dir.md) is not accessible and ChromeDriver cannot create a new profile there or something like this.

Unfortunately there is no way to specify the user data directory using Chrome Driver Config, you might want to switch to [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and instantiate the ChromeDriver using [Groovy code](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black).

Comment: Does that means I should not use the Chromedriver and use Groovy code to launch the browser? but can I still use Webdriver sampler? Can you please provide me sample script to launch the browser in groovy script. That would be great. Thanks