# unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally error using user-data-dir argument with headless chrome through Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless, chrome-profile

I'm in a scraping project and I'm trying to get a page of course.

Here is the code I'm using to open the page:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=selenium")
print("Opening browser")
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver", options=chrome_options)
print("getting request")
driver.get("http://www.tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?ParTree=15131F")
print("starting wait")
time.sleep(10)
response = driver.page_source
print("got response, quitting...")
driver.quit()
```

### my problem

The problem is that it does nothing when it reachs `driver.get()` I mean it neither ends the process nor prints `"starting wait"`. (The problem persists both on my laptop and the server)
I have tried removing the `--headless` option, and it works fine on my laptop (Ubuntu 20.04), but when I upload it to my server and run it there (Ubuntu Server 18.04) it chrome crashes (exception message below)

> Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
> (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
> (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

So I have came to conclusion that I have to use `--headless` option since there is no GUI on my server and chrome crashes when it isn't there.

#### In conclusion I need help to troubleshoot the problem of infinite waiting on `driver.get()`

PS: I can run run the code below with no problem which is weird for me:

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=selenium")
browser = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver', options=chrome_options)
print("open browser")
browser.get("https://www.codal.ir")
print("get")
time.sleep(10)
response = browser.page_source
print("response")
browser.quit()
```

Comment: Does the code work from your own computer/laptop?

Are you able to run curl http://www.tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?ParTree=15131F on your server?

Comment: @MenyIssakov the problem of waiting is both on my laptop and server, and I can run the link on curl on the server

Comment: I'm not familiar with the internals, but it won't work for me unless I remove (chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=selenium"))

Comment: @MenyIssakov Thanks, I hadn't noticed that. seems like many people have the problem having both headless and user-data-dir. by the way, I added two three new arguments: ```chrome_options.add_argument('--profile-directory=selenium')
    chrome_options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1400x1000")``` and now it waits on response = browser.page_source (not the 10 second sleep)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have created a [Chrome Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49270109/how-to-open-a-chrome-profile-through-python/49280195#49280195) by the name **selenium** you need to add `--` before the argument `user-data-dir` and pass the *absolute path* of the [Chrome Profile Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50635087/how-to-open-a-chrome-profile-through-user-data-dir-argument-of-selenium/50637211#50637211) as follows:

```
chrome_options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=/path/to/chromium-profile/selenium")
```

As an alternative, you can also use the argument **`--profile-directory`** as follows:

```
options.add_argument('--profile-directory=selenium')
```