# I'm trying to use my chrome profile with webdriver but it says its already attached

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-profile

You can see the code which I am using below to use another profile with webdriver. I'm needing to know how this is done since I want to be able to load my current chrome profile in to webdriver

```
options.AddArguments(String.Format(
   "--user-data-dir=\"{0}\"", @"C:\Users\zacha\source\repos\Trial Bot - Test\Trial Bot - Test\bin\Debug\User Data"));
         

            
            driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Users\zacha\source\repos\Trial Bot - Test\Trial Bot - Test\",options);
```

Error when ran:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'unknown error: Could not remove old devtools port file. Perhaps the given user-data-dir at "C:\Users\zacha\source\repos\Trial Bot - Test\Trial Bot - Test\bin\Debug\User Data" is still attached to a running Chrome or
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'unknown error: Could not remove old devtools port file. Perhaps the given user-data-dir at "C:\Users\zacha\source\repos\Trial Bot - Test\Trial Bot - Test\bin\Debug\User Data" is still attached to a running Chrome
```

...implies that the *ChromeDriver* was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. *Chrome Browser* using the *Chrome Profile* through the argument `--user-data-dir` as the desired *Chrome Profile* is still in usage by a running [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) browsing instance.

---

Possibly the [Chrome Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49270109/how-to-open-a-chrome-profile-through-python/49280195#49280195) which you are trying to access through [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) driven [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) initiated *Google Chrome Browsing Context* is the same profile you are accessing manually for your other/debugging tasks i.e. the **`Trial Bot - Test`** profile. So, the [Chrome Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50635087/how-to-open-a-chrome-profile-through-user-data-dir-argument-of-selenium/50637211#50637211) remains locked and not accessable by *ChromeDriver*. Hence you see the error.

As a solution try to use different [Chrome Profiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50635087/how-to-open-a-chrome-profile-through-user-data-dir-argument-of-selenium/50637211#50637211) for different tasks.