# Why doesnt Selenium/Chrome Driver open websites with me auto logged in

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, bots, soundcloud

You guys know how google keeps you signed into different websites? how come whenever I use Selenium/Chrome driver and have it go to a website I'm already signed into, it is like im a fresh user and I have to have Selenium go through the work of signing in, which in some cases I cant because some websites block me from signing in with selenium because they know I'm using a bot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google keeps you signed into different websites through your *Default* profile.

Where as [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) driven [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) initiated [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) *Browsing Context* is opened everytime with a newly crated *temporary profile*.

Comment: Is there a way for me to open it through my Default Profile??

Comment: Of-coarse there are certain ways. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52394408/how-to-use-chrome-profile-in-selenium-webdriver-python-3/52399027#52399027), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49270109/how-to-open-a-chrome-profile-through-python/49280195#49280195) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50635087/how-to-open-a-chrome-profile-through-user-data-dir-argument-of-selenium/50637211#50637211) discussion.