# Selenium successfully accesses default Chrome profile, but fails to auto-login to websites

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-profile

I am running Selenium (4.16.0) from a Python Jupyter Notebook on Mac OSX to automate printing a news article to PDF in Chrome (version 120.0). My code successfully opens Chrome with the Default profile and loads the article, **but does NOT sign me into websites even when I have credentials for them saved in that Chrome profile**:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import json, base64
import pickle
import time


url = "https://www.wsj.com/tech/apple-wins-temporary-reprieve-as-u-s-court-pauses-watch-ban-b3b69830?mod=hp_lead_pos1"

chrome_profile_path = "Users/{myusername}/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome"

# Create a ChromeOptions instance
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()


# Set Chrome options to access Default profile & enable printing
chrome_options.add_argument('--kiosk-printing')
chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=/" + chrome_profile_path)
chrome_options.add_argument("--profile-directory=Default")

# Create a Chrome driver that accesses the default profile
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

print("Navigating to webpage...")

# Navigate to the article of interest
driver.get(url)

print("Opened webpage. Pausing to allow it to load...")

time.sleep(3)

print("Pause complete. Getting cookies...")

cookies = driver.get_cookies()

for cookie in cookies:
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)

time.sleep(3)

print("Printing page to PDF...")

# Prints the page to PDF
result = driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Page.printToPDF', {'landscape': True, 'printBackground': True})

# Save the PDF to a file
with open('article.pdf', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(base64.b64decode(result['data']))

# Close the browser
driver.quit()
print("Process complete.")
```

I configured my code to open Chrome with the default profile because my understanding was that this would [automatically log me into the relevant news site.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70012527/why-doesnt-selenium-chrome-driver-open-websites-with-me-auto-logged-in)

The Default profile stores my credentials for this news site. I confirmed this by manually logging into the news site, quitting Chrome, relaunching, and returning to the same news site - I am already signed in without having to enter credentials.

However, when I quit Chrome and run this code, Chrome launches using my Default profile (I can see this in the top-right hand corner of Chrome) but does not log me into the news site.

To try to overcome this, I added code to ensure the relevant cookies are being accessed and loaded; this does not resolve the issue.

I would be grateful for any advice on how to ensure I remain logged into sites when accessing them using webdriver.

Note: I am running executing the code from a Notebook in a different browser and fully quitting Chrome each time I try this.