# Selenium - Mode Headless doesn't work with user-data-dir

Tags: java, selenium, web-scraping

I use Selenium WebDriver in a WhatsApp Automation and I try to use headless mode with session saved in Chrome, but it doesn't work.

The DriverFactory:

```java
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\4P\\Documents\\DRIVER SELENIUM\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");     
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--window-size=1920,1080");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.72 Safari/537.36 OPR/60.0.3255.170");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\4P\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--remote-debugging-port=9222");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--profile-directory=Profile 1");
        chromeOptions.setBinary("C:\\Users\\4P\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe");
        this.driver = new _ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
        this.driver.manage().window();
        this.js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
```

---

### My chrome version is  94.0.4606.61.

With I remove the headless mode, I can get the session with no problem.

In another PC, I had success with another configuration, but I don't have access anymore to it.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Is there a reason to use such old chrome version? Could you update webdriver (and Chrome browser on your PC)? Latest versions currently are 102,103 ([check this link](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads))

Comment: i try with a new version, but still dont work

Comment: what is the error, it is just not able to start or what?

Comment: is not a error, sorry. Chrome dont get the session saved in user-data, but without headless, it worth

Comment: Sounds like you're doing everything right. Can't say what is the exact issue.. definitely something related to `headless` mode.

Comment: Try https://playwright.dev/python/ it has 3 browsers with headless mode: Chromium, Firefox y webkit.

Comment: So, i returned to Firefox and i gave up chrome

Comment: Not question related, but can you explain me how you're saving the chrome session and how you are accessing to it when the code gets executed again? I've been looking for that for a while now.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50635087/how-to-open-a-chrome-profile-through-user-data-dir-argument-of-selenium  use it